# Latex compile error: \section command creates ! Argument of \@thirdoffive has an extra }

Tags: compilation-error

I am a LaTeX newbie and have run into what seems like a non-trivial issue. I get the following error every time I use `\section`

```
! Argument of \@thirdoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.70 \section{Intro}
```

If I comment out `\section` lines, the error goes away and my PDF shows up correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

**MWE**

```latex
\documentclass{nolta}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\NOLTA}{\textbf{NOLTA}}
\setcounter{page}{01}%%
\title{Example Title}
\AUTHOR{%
\author[a]{Name Author1}{1}\orcid{000-0000-0000-0000}, 
}

\AFFILIATE{%
\affiliate{Institution}{1},
}

\EMAIL{%
\email{example@example.com}{a}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract} 
An example abstract can go here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
KW1, KW2, KW3
\end{keywords}

\maketitle 

\section{Intro}

This is an example intro. 
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: And where does the `nolta` class come from? Additionally, noadays you should never have to pass `dvips` as an option to `graphicx`, and there is no need to load both `color` and `xcolor` the latter superceeds the former.

Comment: I assume you have but have you looked at, https://nolta2022.org/guide4author.html I have just run their template and it worked for me after I made the .sty file